# Alter decision made during review

Tags: feature-request, review, edits

Honest mistake, I accidentally chose the incorrect option when reviewing a newly submitted question. Instead of clicking `Requires Editing`, I accidentally chose `Looks OK`. Then I realised I was not able to revert my decision and try again.

I understand that the whole review process involves several community members reviewing said question to eliminate cases of human error but I'd like to correct my mistake and change my 'vote' - seen as I fully acknowledged my mistake.

Does this functionality currently exist? How likely is it to be implemented? I searched for a similar question here on Meta but was not able to find anything.

EDIT:

It was a genuine misclick. I aimed to press `Requires Editing` but ended up pressing the edge of `Looks OK`.

As mentioned in one of the responses, I'm not sure how appropriate it would be to implement said feature, but I was thinking along the lines of how the comment voting system works. You can 'upvote' a comment. You can remove your 'upvote', but you can't 'upvote' it anymore after that.

Comment: You can't change your decision, but you can start editing it anyway of-course. Use the 'back' feature of your browser and click on the question itself.

Answer (score 4):

I'd argue it should not be implemented, this is coming from someone who has made the same mistake.

I think this because of the following;

You should always carefully consider your decision based on carefully reading through the post in question, a knowledge of the tags (if needed, spam is spam!) and considering the implications of your clicks

I learned this a few times (probably nearly earning myself a review ban in the process, but I can't remember), always take your time, click carefully, and read well IMO

Comment: Agreed. Adding complexity to the review queues just to catch honest mistakes seems like fixing the wrong problem. Minimize the mistakes and don't worry too much about the remainder.